# Blank page created in fast report

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, fastreport

I am currently using Fast Report 4.0 to create reports. I am using multiple pages for generating report. Pages are inserted with conditions. 4th page Header band StartNewPage property is set to "True", I face an issue When the number of records in 3th page detail band are exactly fitting in the page , then a blank page is inserted before 4th Page.

Please help me for the same.

Comment: How do you know that the content on the 3rd page exactly fits the page ? I would say it simply overlaps e.g. by an empty line which generates visually empty 4th page.

Comment: I have Masterdata band on 3rd page. and assume It's recordcount is 10. 10th record is end of the page then Blank page is added. if 10th record is not end of the page then it's working fine.